Update dataset of the Power BI Report
I updated a dataset of the Power BI report using rest api:
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{datasetId}/Default.UpdateDatasources
Then I refreshed the dataset using the api:
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{datasetId}/refreshes
but I don't see any visual changes in the Power BI.
How can I resolve this issue ? Do this APIs take time to update the dataset ?
These are the screenshots of the APIs:
POST API to updated Dataset
POST API to refresh the dataset

How do you know it changed?
It's probably a POST to that URI, did you POST or GET?
And what was the status code returned?

The POST request to update dataset returned status code 200 and The refresh API , which was also a POST request returned 202

@DevPathak For updating the dataset you need to use PATCH request, Refer this MsDoc

Actually I am trying to update the source of the dataset that's why I used the POST request according to documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/update-datasources

Have you got the Status Code 200 OK, after running the endpoint?

Yes , I got the 200

Could u pls,  paste the complete screenshot with query and edit the question?

Which type of data source you are trying to update? There are some Limitation while updating datasource.

@DevPathak Any update on issue?

As mentioned in this MsDocIf you're not using enhanced dataset metadata, it will take 30mins to update data sources operation to complete and after that refresh the dataset.

Got it. Thanks for your help. !!

@DevPathak Posted an answer! which helps for betterment of community.

Initially, I registered Single Tenant Microsoft Entra ID application, Added and Granted delagated type Power BI Service  permission of Dataset.Read.Write.All API permission like below:

Use below authorization endpoint at browser to get authorization_code :
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=<AppID>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=YOUR REDIRECT URI
&response_mode=query
&scope=&scope=https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default
&state=12345



Now, Generated Access token using below token endpoint with below parameters:
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id: <APP_ID>
client_secret: <CLIENT SECRET>
scope:&scope=https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
code:AUTHORIZATION_CODE
client_secret:ClientSecret



NOTE:  For updating datasources of datasets, there are some Limitation, Ensure Only these data sources are supported, SQL Server, Azure SQL Server, Azure Analysis Services, Azure Synapse, OData, SharePoint, Teradata, and SAP HANA.
Microsoft recommends to use enhanced dataset metadata.
As this MsDoc refers, If you're not using enhanced dataset metadata, it will take upto 30mins to update data sources operation to complete and after that refresh the dataset.
After generating access token, use below query to update datasources of dataset:
 POST https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{datasetId}/Default.UpdateDatasources
Request Body:
{
  "updateDetails": [
    {
      "datasourceSelector": {
        "datasourceType": "Sql",
        "connectionDetails": {
          "server": "My-Sql-Server",
          "database": "My-Sql-Database"
        }
      },
      "connectionDetails": {
        "server": "New-Sql-Server",
        "database": "New-Sql-Database"
      }
    },
    {
      "datasourceSelector": {
        "datasourceType": "OData",
        "connectionDetails": {
          "url": "http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc"
        }
      },
      "connectionDetails": {
        "url": "http://services.odata.org/V4/Odata/Northwind.svc"
      }
    }
  ]
}

If you get the response of Status code 200 OK which means updating datasources operation will started successfully. Wait for 30 minutes to complete the operation, and then refresh the dataset.
Use below query to refresh the dataset:
POST https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{datasetId}/refreshes
After running this query, If you get Status Code 202 Accepted which means your data sources of dataset are updated successfully.
References:
Update data source - Dataset
Refresh dataset
